# Issues Ordering SQL Server Results

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Here's a SQLFiddle link to be able to quickly visualize sample data.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48245/8

Basically I'm selecting all runs for each WO that will be on the current Line, that works fine, but I want to order them by the current line's sequence with the runs from the prior line above the run on the current line. I've tried a handful of ideas and none of them have panned out.

For example I want the end result of the sample data to look like:

```
Line    Seq     WO

Line2    1     1221
Line2    2     1222
Line1    8     1234
Line2    3     1234
Line1    2     1235
Line2    4     1235
Line2    5     1240
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just add order by clause like below :

```
SELECT SchLine
        ,SchSeq
        ,SchWO
FROM Schedule 
WHERE SchWO IN (SELECT SchWO FROM Schedule WHERE SchLine= @CurrentLine)
ORDER BY SchWO,SchLine
```

Comment: I'd like to see the overall order of the results to be by the @CurrentLine's Seq so the Operators are seeing the WOs in the order they are on their schedule.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT SchLine
    ,SchSeq
    ,SchWO
FROM Schedule 

-- where clause
order by SchWO
```

Comment: You missed where condition and also one column in order by clause

Comment: he can put where condition as per his need and if you see the result shown in example , it is ordered by "SchWO" only in ascending order, that's why i have put only "SchWO" in order by clause